# Spring Boot Actuator Cannot Show diskSpace Information

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have two Spring Boot application. I've added Spring Boot Actuator both of them. When I run one of them I can see `diskSpace`:

```
{
  "status": "UP",
  "diskSpace": {
    "status": "UP",
    "total": 399055067136,
    "free": 346446485504,
    "threshold": 10485760
  }
}
```

However at other service I can only see:

```
{
  "status": "UP"
}
```

Even I add that property to second service:

```
management:
  health:
    diskspace:
      enabled: true
```

I still cannot see `diskSpace` information. When I debug the system I see that such properties are collected but not returned to UI. What can be the problem?

Comment: any possibility that you can share the code for the second actuator where you have implemented the  DiskSpaceHealthIndicator

Comment: I didn't implement a custom health indicator. I've just added the actuator dependency.

Comment: what is the threshold you defined for low disk space.

Comment: I run that services at same machine. One of them shows details and the other one is not. So, problem should not be related to threshold. Only difference is there is no web security enabled at second application.

Comment: /health and /info endpoints doesnt fall under sensitive end points so your web security settings should not affect them.  just to make sure you can add endpoints.beans.sensitive=false to your property file  and rerun you application.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because only ADMINs are authorized to see any more info than this

```
{
  "status": "UP"
}
```

To see all the metrics, authenticate with any user who has a spring security role ADMIN.

**Or**

(less preferable option)
Disable security for actuator endpoint like this

in application properties `yaml` file

```
management:
   security:
      enabled: false
```

Comment: I've debugged the code and you are right. It says:  

`if (exposeHealthDetails(principal)) {
   return this.cached;
  }
return Health.status(this.cached.getStatus()).build();`

I've disabled the login mechanism at application. But I've also set 

`endpoints:
  health:
    sensitive: false`

However Spring still wants an authenticated user. As far as I see, even authentication is enabled and sensitive is false it should be an ADMIN user to access such information.

Comment: A question for my understanding in this case.  why in your first spring boot application you see all the info. Are you admin in that ?

Answer (score 2):

In case if you are using spring security which is by default ON for actuator endpoints, you can disable it in your yml file -

```
management:
   security:
      enabled: false
```

Comment: that helped me.

Answer (score 1):

`management.security.enabled` is **deprecated** now.

You can get full health details by adding a line in `application.properties`:

```
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a line in application.properties:

```
management.endpoint.health.show-details = always
```

this made health show details to all users other than authorized people.

Answer (score -1):

Spring boot actuator's HealthIndicator checks available disk space and reports a status of Status#DOWN when it drops below a configurable threshold.

so in your case for the second application the free space available is more than the threshold hence hou don't see any thing being reported.

you probably  can debug and see in your code the values free disk space and the threshold.

let me know if this make sense...